# radio-group changing value

Tags: angular, ionic4

l am try to make weather app using ionic 4 and angular . l have multiple cities , so l want to use radio group to change cities via coordinates values . my problem is when l run my app l got nothing result from data json ! l got undefined . even checked is not working so l have to checked manual

radio group :

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="cities">
    <ion-list-header>
    <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
  </ion-list-header>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Muscat</ion-label>
    <ion-radio slot="start" value="26.2105,56.244" checked></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Dubia</ion-label>
    <ion-radio slot="start" value="26.161722,56.23672"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```

code :

```
export class Tab1Page {
  weather:any;
  cities: string;

  constructor(private https: HttpClient) {
    this.test()
  }

  onCitiesChanged(data){
    console.log(data.detail.value);
  }

  async test (){
    this.https.get('weather/'+this.cities+'.json')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.weather = data
    })
  }
}
```

url result console `weather/undefined.json`

Comment: so you want to get the values from json when you click the radio button?

Comment: yes , when l change value nothing to show and also checked default not working

Comment: use the change event for radio group and check if you get the selected value

Comment: can you edit my code ? l am beginner

Comment: you can check now

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan there is no answer to see !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189225/discussion-between-sivaramakrishnan-and-pabloescobar).

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan Don't answer a question by editing the question itself, either comment the solution, or if you feel like it's worth writing an answer, then do that. I did a rollback to the state the question was before, but for future please remember this :) Thanks!

Comment: @AJT_82 it is same problem he doesn't work

Comment: @AJT_82 can you help me please ?

Comment: @pabloescobar Your code looks correct to me and should work. But it's not a [mcve] so we can only guess how the rest of the code looks like that is needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: ... and if you need an initial value for `cities`, don't use `checked`, assign the value to the `cities`, because now intially it's undefined, and actually that option wouldn't actually be checked, as ngModel overrides that.

Comment: @AJT_82 you can see my update code question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/radio-group) you can use the `ionChange` event or you can use `ngModel`. If you want to use the selected `cities` value when it is assigned or changed you need to use the `ionChange` event. See the code below that makes an http call when the value changes.

#### A note about `ionChange`

When you subscribe to `ionChange` the method is fired when first initialized. You do not have to set an additional value in the component/typescript file. You should not be making any calls in the constructor **and** there is no need to in this case as the method callback will be fired as soon as the value has been set which happens right after the html is rendered as the html is assigning the initial selection with the `checked` attribute.

#### Code

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-zcl6ha)

**template.html**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-radio-group (ionChange)="onCitiesChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="cities">
        <ion-list-header>
            <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Muscat</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start" value="26.2105,56.244" checked></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Dubia</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start" value="26.161722,56.23672"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private https: HttpClient) {/* nothing else */}

cities: string;
onCitiesChanged(data){
    this.https.get('weather/'+this.cities+'.json')
      .subscribe(data => this.weather = data);
}
```

Comment: OP is using ngModel, it works just as well, the value is stored in `cities`, but then again we do not know when `test()` is called so... there can be an issue somewhere else.

Comment: @pabloescobar - see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-zcl6ha) or the code above which is copied from the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-zcl6ha).

Comment: stackblitz shows: Error in /~/src/main.ts (3:14) Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: `ionChange` is not needed, ngModel works just as well :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-cfl9uo?file=src/app/app.component.html, i.e code that OP is already showing :)

Comment: @AJT_82 - I changed it 4 min. ago based on your initial feedback. The above code only uses `ionChange` to illustrate that the event is firing by logging the call to `console.log`

Comment: @WilliamLohan - I just loaded that same link again in Chrome, no errors. Maybe the error is browser specific??

Comment: @pabloescobar - you need to make that `http` call when the value is assigned or changes. See the modified code above and subscribe to `ionChange`.

Comment: l did that but it same

Comment: @pabloescobar - see the https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-zcl6ha , open the console of the browser and you will see the value being assigned when the template html loads and also any time it changes.

Comment: @pabloescobar - glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `test()` in the constructor, which would not be recommended. Also you have not set an initial value for `cities`, so it would correctly be `undefined`.

Also, don't use `checked`, set the intial value to the `ngModel`, like:

`cities = '26.2105,56.244'`

`checked` has no effect here, since `cities` is `undefined`.

Have a click event or something when user has chosen an option, and then call `test`. That is one option or at least call it in `OnInit`. I'm a strong believer that anything that does not need to be called in `constructor`, shouldn't. We have `OnInit` for just that purpose! :)

Comment: so how can l  load the default city first then when click on change city ?

Comment: set the intial value to `cities`, the option you would want to have checked.

Comment: can you give me example ! for et the intial value to cities, the option you would want to have checked ?

Comment: I have, look at the answer `cities = '26.2105,56.244'`

Comment: @pabloescobar See stackblitz and console: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-a3bbde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts